# как на C без <string.h> разделить строку на слова по указанным символам. Доходит до 1 + и не перешагивает дальше

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char *str = "qtga+agafg+1354";
    size_t p = 1;
    while (*str++ != '\0') { // Перебираем строку до нуля
        if (*str == '+') { // Ищем символ на котором прерываемся
            return p;
            p++; // шагаем дальше`введите сюда код`
        }
        printf("%c", *str);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Просто сами реализуйте [strchr](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html)

Answer (score 1):

> Доходит до 1 + и не перешагивает дальше

А что Вы ожидаете? У вас же в программе написано:

```
if (*str == '+') { // Ищем символ на котором прерываемся
            return p;
            p++; // шагаем дальше`введите сюда код`
        }
```

Программа доходит до первого плюса и выполняет *return*... Т.е. выполняется **завершение** всей программы!

И строка

```
 p++; // шагаем дальше`введите сюда код`
```

абсолютно бессмысленна. Она **никогда** не выполнится.

Answer (score 0):

Для поиска символа в строке удобно использовать функцию [strchr()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html), которую несложно реализовать самому. Например, так:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push  
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdiscarded-qualifiers"
char *
Strchr (const char *s, int c)
{
  while (*s) {
    if (*s == c)
      return s;
    s++;
  }

  return (char *)(c ? 0 : s);
  // From the strchr manpage:
  // The terminating  null byte is considered part of the string, so that if c is specified as '\0', these function return a pointer to the terminator.
}
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

После ее вызова в цикле очередное искомое слово будет начинаться с ее аргумента и заканчиваться перед возвращаемым ей указателем.

Тогда остальная программа, выбирающая слова из строки и печатающая их, может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void
print_word (const char *s, size_t n)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    putchar(s[i]);
  putchar('\n');
}

char *Strchr (const char *s, int c);

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char *str = "qtga+agafg+1354";
  printf("Obtain words from `%s` by `+`\n", str);
  
  char *w = str, *t;

  while ((t = Strchr(w, '+'))) {
    size_t n = t - w;  // длина слова
    print_word(w, n);
    w = t + 1;         // начало следующего слова
  }
  printf("last word: <%s>\n", w);
      
  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Comment: Круто, берём константу, затыкаем компилятору рот, валимся при работе с RO объектами. Где вы такой код нашли?

Comment: @0andriy, где вы увидели модификацию RO объектов? Прототип, естественно, из [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html). `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdiscarded-qualifiers"` теперь приходится добавлять, чтобы заткнуть "умников", обновивших компайлер